# ForEach javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, estoy intentanto establecer el metodo forEach para la clase Array en javascript , para usarlo en una funcion que me agregue cada elemento a una cadena. El objeto es un NodeofList, pero no puedo hacer:

```
    NodeofList<Element>.forEach=funcion(){};
```

El que codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    Array.forEach += function (callback) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    callback(this[i], i, this);
    };
```

Y aqui es donde intento utilizarlo:

```
    function funcionxml() {



     var mixml;
     var stringaMostrar = " ";//(en realidad esta variable la tengo como global)

     if (mipeticion.readyState == 4 && mipeticion.status == 200) {

        mixml = mipeticion.responseXML;
        var arrayPersonas = mixml.getElementsByTagName("persona");
        arrayPersonas.forEach(function (element, index, lista) {
            stringaMostrar += element.getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + " " + element.getElementsByTagName("apellidos")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "\n";
        });


        document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML = stringaMostrar;
     }
    }
```

El error que recibo es :
arrayPersonas.forEach no es una función.

Comment: Tengo la duda si el metodo o la propiedad forEach debo establecerla en la clase Array , en Iterator ,o en otra distinta ya que el tipo de mi objeto es NodeofList<Element> ,

Comment: Hola Alexmaister, si entiendo, lo que quieres lograr es una funcion forEach nueva con funcionalidades tuyas no ? y que lo puedes aplicarlo a cualquier array ?

Comment: Si , pero mi variable arrayPersonas , es un objeto NodeofList<Element> que viene de un archivo xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque puedas acceder a sus posiciones,  NO es un array , sino un HTMLCollection , como por ejemplo cuando haces:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")
```

Esto devuelve un HTMLCollection, al cual puedes acceder a sus indices, pero NO a los métodos de la clase Array , ya que NO lo es.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("P"),
    toArray = Array.from(elems);
```

`Array.from(Elemento iterable)` , CREA un array desde un objeto iterable, como lo es un HTMLCollection , y por qué sé que es iterable ? Por que puedes acceder a sus indices e iterar sobre él con un ciclo for.

Comment: Gracias , voy a probarlo

Comment: Edite la respuesta

Comment: Ahi esta , eso es lo que estaba diciendo, en la documentacion me decia que lo hiciese a iteraleble , entonces intente Itelarable.forEach=function() pero no podia. Asi se soluciona, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Supongo que no podia modificar el metodo forEach de Iterable porque es una interfaz (supongo , no lo se exactamente), y no conocia Array.from() jeje gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

> Te dejo como agregarle un nuevo metodo a un objeto mediante sus
>   prototype. Estabas muy cerca de lograrlo. Saludos.

```js
//Seteo el nuevo metodo del objeto Array
Array.prototype.myNewForEach = function(callback) {
  for (var a = 0; a < this.length; a++) {
    callback(this[a], a, this)
  }
}

// Forma de utilizarlo
var a = ["a", "b"]
a.myNewForEach(function(currentValue, index, array) {
  console.log("Index:", index)
  console.log("Elemento:", currentValue)
  console.log("Array:", array)
})
```

Comment: Voy a ver si me sirve asi para mi arrayPersonas , que como digo no se si es un array ya que aunq lo trato como tal pudiendo acceder a sus diferentes posiciones (arraPersonas[p]) en el debugger veo que es de tipo NodeofList<Element>

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices, que cosa muestra un NodeofList?